# How to collect Instagram App Secret to generate a long-lived token?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

On [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) I generate the access token and with it I can publish the image on my Instagram:

[image]

For publish:

```
function InstagramPost() {
  const access_token = 'GENERATE ACESS TOKEN';
  const instagram_business_account = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY';
  
  const image = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/95/Test_image.jpg';
  const text = 'Hello World';
  var formData = {
    'image_url': image,
    'caption': text,
    'access_token': access_token
  };
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formData
  };
  const container = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/' + instagram_business_account + '/media';

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(container, options);

  const creation = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(creation);
  var creationId = data.id
  var formDataPublish = {
      'creation_id': creationId,
      'access_token': access_token
  };
  var optionsPublish = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formDataPublish
  };
  const sendinstagram = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/' + instagram_business_account + '/media_publish';
  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(sendinstagram, optionsPublish);
}
```

Now I want to take this access token and generate a [long-lived](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/long-lived-access-tokens) one with it!

It asks for *Instagram App Secret*, but that path indicated `(App Dashboard > Products > Instagram > Basic Display > Instagram App Secret)` doesn't exist in *App Dashboard*!

[image]

I tried using the *App secret* as a parameter:

[image]

```
"https://graph.instagram.com/access_token
  ?grant_type=ig_exchange_token
  &client_secret={App Secret Key}
  &access_token={short-lived-access-token}"
```

But this error occurs:

```
Sorry, this content isn't available right now
```

The Facebook API is 100% accessible, so that's not the problem.

Comment: I'm getting the same error trying to get a long lived token. Find any solution? If we're both getting it at the same time, and I can't find any other posts about this specifically online, I'm guessing it's likely a problem on their end. Your Instagram app secret is found by going to Instagram Basic Display > and you'll see "Instagram App Secret"

Comment: @exile97 Could you add in your answer the images of where I find this Instagram Basic Display? I couldn't find it anywhere. Please!

Comment: Added picture. You need to add the Basic Display to your app first if you haven't already. Follow this tutorial if needed [link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/getting-started-with-the-instagram-basic-display-api-5124c92c4935)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference in approach between **Basic Display** and **Instagram Graph API for Business Account**.

So the way to convert a short-lived token to a long-lived token for Instagram Business Account is:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/{graph-api-version}/oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&          
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={your-short-lived-access-token}"
```

Note that `Instagram App Secret` is not used, instead, use `App Id` and `App Secret`.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript/NodeJS I couldn't get it working at all (also on PostMan), I was using the `request` library.

Changed my code to:

```
const respLong = await axios.get(`https://graph.instagram.com/access_token?grant_type=ig_exchange_token&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}&access_token=${accessTokenShort.toString()}`);
```

And magically this works. I can't tell you why what seems to be the exact same request in Postman and the `request` library doesn't work.

See pic of the url to get app secret (add your app ID) is: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID(number)/instagram-basic-display/basic-display/
[image]